# SQL query that merges two tables together with a where clause

Tags: sql

Hi I want to search through table 2 with a value (names CustID) from table 1, and if all the values are found in table 2 (CustID) that matches table 1 (CustID) the values must be shown together with all the values from table 1 that does not match table 2's values.

Is it possible to do it this way and if it is can you please show me how, I need this for a project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a LEFT JOIN operator. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a "LEFT" JOIN, which will pull up all records in table1 plus the matching ones in table2.

SELECT A.*,B.* FROM table1 A LEFT JOIN table2 B ON A.CustID = B.CustID